# magento configurable product filter

Tags: php, magento, configurable-product, static-block

I made a new static block containing featured products. (type = configurable product)
Each product is based on that configurable product (different colors)

For each configurable product in my static block, I want to put a select box where I can select the color. When you have selected a color, you can add that product to your cart.

How am I able to do this (using a product list template)?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a nice explanation](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/display-multiple-configurable-products-with-options-on-one-page-in-magento/) (and full code) on how to do that provided by the guys at Inchoo.
It involves changing the product list template and the javascript file that handles the product price reloading.
The code is kind of long to post here.